# sequence of wait and notify of threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blocking

I wrote a producer/consumer program as below.

```
 package com.myjava.concurrency.basics.waitnotify;
 import java.util.PriorityQueue;
 import java.util.Queue;

public class SharedObject {

private Queue<String> dataObject;

private final Object objLock = new Object();

public SharedObject() {
    dataObject = new PriorityQueue<String>(1);
}

public void writeData(String data) {
    synchronized (objLock) {
        while (!dataObject.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Producer:Waiting");
            try {
                objLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dataObject.offer(data);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s", 
        Thread.currentThread().getName(), data));
        objLock.notify();
    }
}

public String readData() {
    String result = null;
    synchronized (objLock) {
        while (dataObject.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Consumer:Waiting");
            try {
                objLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        result = dataObject.poll();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s", 
        Thread.currentThread().getName(), result));
        objLock.notify();
    }
    return result;
}
}


 package com.myjava.concurrency.basics.waitnotify;

 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;

 public class TestWaitNotify {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject();

    List<String> fruitsList = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");
    int listSize = fruitsList.size();

    Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("producer thread started");
        fruitsList.forEach(p -> {
            sharedObject.writeData(p);
        });
    }, "producer");

    Thread consumer = new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("consumer thread started");
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            sharedObject.readData();
        }
    }, "consumer");

    consumer.start();
    producer.start();

}
}
```

I got the output, as below:

```
 producer thread started
 consumer thread started
 Consumer:Waiting
 producer : Apple
 Producer:Waiting
 consumer : Apple
 Consumer:Waiting
 producer : Banana
 Producer:Waiting
 consumer : Banana
 Consumer:Waiting
 producer : Orange
 consumer : Orange
```

Here is my question:

I expected the below sequence, with this program:

```
     producer thread started
     consumer thread started
     Consumer:Waiting  // assuming consumer thread begins first
     producer : Apple
     consumer : Apple
     producer : Banana
     consumer : Banana
     producer : Orange
     consumer : Orange
```

Only consumer thread should enter in wait mode only once. After the first notify, the threads should not enter while loop because when producer thread has the object lock, consumer should wait for the lock and when consumer releases the lock the producer should acquire the lock.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.notify() will wake up a thread waiting on the lock but it doesn't necessarily prioritize it to acquire next and the javadoc identifies this behavior:

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object. **The awakened thread will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object**.

Likely what is happening is the thread that just relinquished the lock is immediately acquiring it again in front of the thread you expect. If you put a sleep after the notify (but **not** in the synchronized block) you're likely to see the output you were expecting. In this cause you're forcing that thread to effectively yield to the other thread that has been notified.

Comment: "the thread that just relinquished the lock is immediately acquiring it again" , this is the only possibility I can see. But, my understanding is by the time the consumer releases the lock the producer should be ahead of the consumer thread for acquiring lock, because producer is waiting since long time compare to consumer thread. Thanks @John

Comment: I added print statement at the beginning and ending of each synchronized block of the code and noticed that the thread(eg.producer) that is releasing the lock is the one that acquiring immediately. The thread(consumer in this case) that is in wait is acquiring the lock only when the current thread(i.e producer) moved to wait state. So, @John's explanation is correct and in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Examine this tutorial may could help you, it seem's very similiar to your problem even it only differences from your example is method signs they have `synchronized` keyword by the way.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm

Comment: After adding print statement inside the while loop of that program, I got the output that matches with mine. Consumer is going to wait mode just after finishing its iteration, thats the point Im confused about.
Producer #1 put: 0
Consumer #1 got: 0
Consumer:Waiting
Producer #1 put: 1
Consumer #1 got: 1
Consumer:Waiting
So, this is not helpful. However, I am curious to know the reason but not the similar/same output.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while (dataObject.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Consumer:Waiting");
```

The consumer *consumes* one entry. But at the same time, the queue is **locked**, so nothing can be added in the meantime.

So the producer has to wait for the consumer to consume, then the consumer has to wait for the producer to put something new in.

Therefore the following assumption

> Only consumer thread should enter in wait mode only once.

is wrong.

Comment: "The consumer consumes one entry. But at the same time, the queue is locked, so nothing can be added in the meantime." I agree till this point. But look at the program, after consumer consumes the data, it calls notify(). At this moment the second iteration of the producer thread is waiting to acquire the lock at the synchronized statement . right? and it is not inside the while loop because the lock is still with consumer at this moment. When the consumer thread releases the lock after finishing notify(), it goes for next iteration.

Comment: Continuation to the above comment. When the producer thread obtained the lock in the second iteration, the dataObject.isEmpty() should be definitely true and hence it should't enter into the while loop. Based on this assumption, I expected the only 'consumer' should enter while loop only once and after that it is just a game of lock release/acquire between producer/consumer.